# Html - Footer Tag

Tags: html, footer

I have been looking at some html files that have a footer tag. I was wondering what it does and how it is used? Also, what are some of the default settings that come with the footer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily solvable by searching on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question,

First of all the footer tag is declared like this: `<footer> </footer>`

Second the footer is the section of the html that would go under the body. If you add a background color it would simply just be under the page

Lastly the footer has no default settings, so you will have to edit it in the CSS or inline CSS.

Comment: Sorry to say but your answer is totally wrong, your second and last point makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

By convention an Html [footer](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/footer) usually contains information about the page like author and copyright data.

Comment: I thought meta was supposed to go in the head? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Your right, I abused the term...